# object oriented programming in android

Tags: java, android

I want to use a method in one of my classes in another class , my code doesn't have any error but when I run the project I get "unfortunately project *** hast stopped" error.
and when I copy the method instead of creating object and so on I run the program without any problem , can any one tell me what may be the problem ?

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String p = "+989357835774";
    String m = "test";
    SendSMS sms = new SendSMS();
    sms.sms(p, m);
}


public class SendSMS extends Activity {

    public void sms (String phonno , String Message){
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SendSMS.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phonno, "+9891100500", Message , pi, null);  
    }
}
```

these are my errors  :

```
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3655)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at com.example.finalproject3.SendSMS.sms(SendSMS.java:15)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at com.example.finalproject3.Pizza$1$2.onClick(Pizza.java:53)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17078)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-23 19:31:00.065: E/AndroidRuntime(9985):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us help you, please post the complete error message caused by your app. You can find the error message in the LogCat view in Eclipse or by running `adb logcat` from the command-line.

Comment: Post the `logcat` trace, to find out what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: `sth like that`. Very explicite. Care to add, for example, the stacktrace ?

Comment: Also, to get the help you want, you should take the time to make your code readable by following some common formatting conventions, such as indentation styles.

Comment: Additionally, where is this `onClick()` method and how are you calling it?

Comment: these are my complete error massages...I edited my question ! :)

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the error message. It is currently impossible to read. (Note that you can get help with formatting by clicking the ? button above the text area where you edit your question.)

Comment: Thank you for noticing and sorry !

Comment: dont directly call methods of one activity from another activity.  Build an intent and send it.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you are saying? I'm a little bit new to such programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SendSMS` class is an `Activity`. You should never instantiate an Activity yourself, because none of the life cycle methods will be called then. Let the system start your Activities (using intents).

If you just need a normal class that you instantiate don't inherit `Activity`.

To get access to methods only found in `Activity` or `Context` pass in a valid `Context` in your class constructor.

Assuming your `onClick` method is defined in an Activity:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String p = "+989357835774";
    String m = "test";
    SendSMS sms = new SendSMS(this);
    sms.sms(p, m);
}


public class SendSMS {

    private Context context;

    public SendSMS(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void sms (String phonno , String Message){
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, YourActivity.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phonno, "+9891100500", Message , pi, null);  
    }
}
```

Comment: well when I delete " extend Activity" in my SendSMS class I got error in this line :
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
       new Intent(this, SendSMS.class), 0);

Comment: I'll be glad if u can give me an example of what you are saying ...I'm new in programming :)

Comment: @eng.m.a You should probably walk through tutorials for android development.

Comment: thank you Henry but why I have still error in this line ?:
 public void sms (String phonno , String Message){
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, SendSMS.class), 0);                
(in getActivity part)

Comment: The `SendSMS.class` was still wrong. But this should not cause a compile error. Which error did you get?

Comment: now I changed "SendSMS.class" with "pizza.class" (which is the name of my activity class that I want to use "sms" method in it , now I got no error but I get error in this line :
SendSMS sms = new SendSMS(this);

Comment: which says " the cunstructor SendSMS is undifiend"

Comment: So your `onClick` method is not directly defined in an Activity but maybe in an anonymous inner class? If this is the case try `SendSMS sms = new SendSMS(pizza.this);`